# Kubernetes Celery autoscaling doesn't distribute tasks evenly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, celery, kubernetes, kops

I have built an application that uses celery to run a task asynchronously. I have the celery working on 2 Kubernetes pods that is being hosted on an Amazon AWS m4.large instance.

I also have set up horizontal pod autoscaling so that the pods would scale when CPU utilization goes above 80%. I have an autoscaling group in AWS that also scales when instance CPU utilization reaches over 80%.

For about an hour, the cluster scales to 5 instances all running at ~100% CPU utilization but then all other celery pods run at ~2% and only one is running at ~100%. There are still many tasks in the queue, but it seems that only one of my pods is running at full potential.

What is happening here and how can I evenly distribute tasks such that all 5 pods run at similar CPU utilization until all tasks are completed?

When running kubectl top pods. One of my pods runs 1900 milliCPUs and others run at 1 milliCPUs.

Comment: have you checked what was idle worker doing? I guess they were blocked by a task.

Comment: @StackyStack did you ever figure this out? What do you know?

Comment: @Dagrooms Our scheduler started assigning tasks to workers only in that pod and only when there was a higher CPU usage on that pod did others spin up. So in the middle of a lot of jobs, it would distribute evenly but the first container had some extra tasks to finish towards the end. We fixed by setting a slightly higher min pod in the horizontal pod autoscaler

Comment: @StackyStack you should post your solution as the answer